# Forecast function in R does not seem to work with my arima model?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I am attempting to do some forecasting with some time series data on temperature at an airport in Arkansas (daily for the year of 2018, so 365 observations in total, no missing values as well). To give an idea of how the data looks, it is something like this:

```
Date      Temp
1/1/2018  33.7
1/2/2018  26.2
1/3/2018  32.1
```

Since this is my first time attempting forecasting though, I thought it made sense to slice off say, the final 5 observations of my dataset and attempt to forecast those observations with a training/testing set of my data, as so:

```
train_series= WeatherTS[1:360]
test_series=WeatherTS[361:365]
```

I used the auto.arima function in R to attempt to find the best arima model possible for the training set of data, as provided here (the best model with this function turned out to be (1,1,3)):

```
auto.arima(train_series)
fitarima <- arima(train_series, order=c(1,1,3))
```

From here, after running diagnostics with the residuals and so on of this arima model and being satisfied enough, I attempted to do some forecasting now with all this in mind, coded as such:

```
forecastingattempt <- forecast(fitarima, level=c(95), h=5)
```

However, when I attempt to run this line in R, I receive this error message:

Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error message? Is it not possible to do this sort of forecasting attempt with an arima model? I am unsure why it thinks the arima model has no observations, so any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
As per Marco's request, here is the output when utilizing the command dput(WeatherTS):

```
structure(c(33.7, 26.2, 32.1, 29.4, 25.5, 32.7, 32, 17.4, 4.2, 
9.2, 28.1, 32.9, 29.9, 36, 35.4, 30, 27.6, 25.8, 19.4, 7.5, -0.4, 
-4.6, -8.1, -11.6, -11.6, -8, 0.1, 1.5, 12.9, 14, 7.9, 3.1, 0, 
7, 13.5, 9.5, 29.4, 22.5, 9.7, 25.7, 32.9, 32.3, 34.1, 29.1, 
31, 22.5, 26.2, 20.6, 29.4, 29, 28.7, 27.8, 34.5, 24.4, 24.1, 
23.2, 29.4, 19.2, 10.5, 8.7, 23.3, 25.6, 21, 23.9, 27.3, 29.7, 
28.2, 22.2, 20.3, 19, 25.2, 29.8, 28.5, 17.6, 32.2, 34, 34.3, 
32.4, 29.2, 25.6, 22.6, 24.5, 25.4, 28.3, 32.5, 32.6, 31.7, 28, 
26.3, 25.5, 31.9, 32.2, 29.8, 22.3, 25.9, 22.4, 18.9, 27, 32.9, 
39.7, 39.5, 38.7, 39.2, 35.6, 35.5, 35.8, 35.7, 36.6, 37.2, 38.8, 
36.2, 39.3, 37.1, 39.1, 38.1, 36.9, 36.5, 36.5, 39, 38.6, 37.5, 
35.8, 36.8, 37.5, 35.9, 35.4, 37.6, 39.9, 41.2, 39.6, 40.8, 42, 
40.6, 37.7, 35.7, 38.3, 43.1, 44.5, 44.8, 45, 46.9, 47.8, 46.3, 
46.1, 46, 48.8, 48.3, 46.2, 44.1, 45, 45.8, 50.5, 49.1, 51.9, 
48.3, 49.8, 50.8, 48.9, 49.6, 49.3, 58.8, 60.9, 55.3, 56.7, 57, 
54.6, 49.4, 48.8, 50.5, 49, 48.6, 49.4, 50.8, 51.4, 53, 50.8, 
52.4, 50, 50.7, 50.4, 52.3, 54.9, 56.7, 65.4, 60.2, 59, 61.5, 
59.2, 50.7, 48, 49, 48.6, 48.5, 51.4, 48.1, 52, 53.8, 52.2, 53, 
56.7, 58.1, 61.4, 59.6, 54, 55, 57.1, 56.7, 54.2, 54.5, 56.6, 
57.3, 56.5, 52.6, 52.8, 54.5, 61.7, 58, 54.9, 58.1, 54.3, 53.7, 
52.5, 53.6, 57.1, 50.4, 51.2, 48.7, 51.9, 51.7, 52.4, 55.3, 52.1, 
54.2, 51.7, 52.8, 50.3, 50.9, 54.4, 51, 52.9, 48.5, 51.4, 48.2, 
48.9, 50.8, 49.5, 49, 48.9, 52.5, 49.4, 50.4, 51.7, 53.6, 56.4, 
58.9, 56.6, 57.8, 56.5, 52.8, 52.1, 48.8, 49.9, 49.8, 48.2, 49.2, 
48, 46.8, 45.1, 43.4, 47.6, 50.5, 52.7, 52.1, 50.3, 50.1, 48, 
45.8, 46.7, 48, 47.2, 43.1, 46.8, 47.4, 43.6, 46, 43.1, 42.8, 
47.8, 45.5, 45.1, 44.8, 41.3, 35.6, 42.9, 42.3, 40, 38.5, 39.2, 
37.1, 32.8, 25.3, 21.6, 32, 29.4, 25.9, 22, 36.3, 24.4, 25.2, 
33.6, 36, 29.2, 31.3, 27.2, 33.2, 31.6, 31.3, 20.1, 16.1, 35.3, 
40.8, 38.2, 31, 26.8, 25.7, 18, 13.2, 25.5, 21.4, 22.1, 24.8, 
22.5, 13.4, 18.8, 38.8, 34.7, 26.7, 34.4, 37, 29.3, 29.3, 17.2, 
21.1, 30.1, 25.9, 9.1, -4.4, -1.5, 0.1, -1.2, -7.4, -5.5, -7.8, 
-12.3, -4.3, 8.9, 13.1, 4.5, 5.7, 11.7, 16.2, 19.4, -0.4, 15.4, 
35.1), .Tsp = c(2018, 2018.99657768652, 365.25), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Hello Marco, I attempted this but trying to run those lines once more with these edits gives me this error: Error in `[.default(WeatherTS, 1:360, ) : incorrect number of dimensions'

Comment: Could you share in your post the output of the command `dput(WeatherTS)` ?

Comment: Just edited in the output for you Marco

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error on my R 3.6.3.(Win10 64bit). See the output: https://imgur.com/eOs60fI   What package are you using ? `forecast` ?

Comment: I have an update, but to answer your question, yes I was using the forecast package along with others during my time series analysis. I instead used the Arima() function as opposed to arima(), the main difference being the former is a function that allows a drift term, and my forecasting line in R seems to run now. I also believe that maybe some of the other packages I ran in conjunction with forecast was causing the error I kept facing, as closing my R script, reopening it, and only enabling the forecast package causes the forecast line to work with the regular arima() function